# Evaluate the Riemann sum

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

If
$\mathrm{f}\left(x\right) = 2\cos\left(x\right)$
$ 0 \leq x \leq 3\pi/4$

evaluate the Riemann sum with 
$n = 6$,
 taking the sample points to be left endpoints. ( Round your answer to six decimal places ).

I've tried this several times now by using
$\delta x = \pi/8$ and doing:

$$
\frac{\pi}{8}\left[2\cos\left(0\right) +
2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) +
2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{8}\right) +\cdots + 2\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{8}\right)\right]
$$

and the answer I keep coming up with is $4.711374$ but my online homework is telling me this is wrong. Can anybody help ?.

Edit: I tried subtracting a $\pi/8$ from each value inside the cosine functions and got $3.926437$ can anyone tell me if this is correct ?.

Comment: Use $\cos{(k \pi/8)} = \operatorname{Re}{e^{i k \pi/8}}$ and add up the resulting geometric series.

Comment: Be sure that your calculator is in radian mode.

Comment: Your set-up looks fine.  You calculation is off.  Right sum $2.06$, Left sum $0.72,$  Trapezoid rule  $1.40$  Midpoint rule $1.42.$  Also note that $\cos (\frac {\pi}{2}-x) = - \cos (\frac {\pi}{2}+x)$  So, there is a little bit less calculating necessary than you show.

Comment: I notice I have my left sum and right sum's backward.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is right.

You might make use of the fact that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$ and that
$$
\cos \left(\frac{5\pi}{8} \right) = -\cos \left(\frac{3\pi}{8} \right)
$$
to simplify your sum to
$$
\frac{\pi}{8} \left( 2\cos (0) + 2\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{8} \right) 
+2 \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{8} \right) \right)
$$
so you only need to sum three things instead of six, and so you'll have fewer opportunities for error!